# L^1 and almost everywhere convergence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am trying to get examples of sequences that converge in $L^1$ but not almost everywhere and vice versa. I know solutions to this are available on this website and elsewhere, but I think I have particularly simple examples that I did not see anywhere, and am wondering if maybe I am missing something. So here goes:

**$L^1$ but not a.e.**

Let $X_n \sim$ Bernoulli($1/n$) be independent and $X \equiv 0$. Then, $\mathbb{E}(X_n - X) = 1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. But by Borel-Cantelli $\limsup_{n \to \infty}X_n = 1$ almost surely. Here I saw most sources give the example of the typewriter sequence.

**a.e. but not $L^1$**

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure. Let $f_n = 1_{[n, n +1]}$ and $f \equiv 0$. Then, $f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$ almost everywhere. But,

$$
\int |f_n - f|d\lambda = \int 1_{[n, n +1]} d\lambda = \lambda ([n, n+1]) = 1,
$$
which obviously does not tend to $0$.

Are my solutions correct?

Comment: These are both pretty famous examples, actually. They're both correct, once you include independence in the first one. (Borel-Cantelli in that direction requires independence.)

Comment: It is correct except that you forgot to mention the crucial hypothesis  of independence in the first part. Borel-Cantelli requires independence.

Comment: @geetha290krm Right, fixed it. Thanks!